# Aurelia configure Router becomes page event?

Tags: javascript, router

most of Aurelia github examples says we need to call configure() inside the constructor() method 
ex:

```
 constructor(router) {
    this.router = router;
    this.configure();
  }

  configure() {
    this.router.configure(config => {
      config.title = 'Aurelia';
      config.map([
        { route: ['','welcome'],  moduleId: 'welcome',      nav: true, title:'Welcome' },
        { route: 'flickr',        moduleId: 'flickr',       nav: true },
        { route: 'child-router',  moduleId: 'child-router', nav: true, title:'Child Router' }
      ]);
    });    
  }
```

but i noted latest example had method   configureRouter(config, router) which looks self executing without calling form different method. (or at least i cant find it ) 
 any way how can we find the complete page lifecycle of Aurelia  (throughout the screen activation lifecycle)?

Comment: The router config is done like this: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-es2016-webpack/src/app.js

Comment: This shows how aurelia executes something on the activation of a route: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-es2016-webpack/src/users.js

Comment: I can't find in the docs anything about the router stuff, however I do know there is an activate and deactivate both you can return promises from if you want to do async functions before its loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This eBook is not completed "https://leanpub.com/aurelia-for-real-world-applications" only 60% yet. any way looks there are five methods are called in the following order.(throughout the screen activation life-cycle).

```
1) configureRouter(config, router)
2) canActivate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction)
3) activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction)
4) canDeactivate()
5) deactivate()
```

Comment: `configureRouter` is step 3, at least in the `App`.